# Hide video controls in Silverlight Web player

Tags: html, video, silverlight, controls, video-player

My Silverlight player code:

```
 <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
              <param name="source" value="SmoothStreamingPlayer.xap"/>
              <param name="background" value="black" />
              <param name="enableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />
              <param name="maxFramerate" value="25" />
              <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
              <param name="autoUpgrade" value="false" />
          <param name="InitParams" value="mediaurl=http://stream.com/name.isml/Manifest" />
              <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
                <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
              </a>
            </object>
```

So when I watch video, controls are always visible. Is thre some way to hide them?

Answer (score 0):

This has instructions you to make a custom player where you can specify the controls:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff646972.aspx